# How to sync app data with MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mongoose, asyncstorage

I have an array of todos in AsyncStorage of a react-native app which I want to sync with my MongoDB database. Sync in the sense that it should do these things:

1. Delete the old tasks in DB which are not present in app.
2. Update the old tasks which are already present in DB but edited (task title / completed state) in app.
3. Add the tasks which are newly added in app but not yet saved in DB.

How can I acheive this? I am using express, node and mongoose in backend.
Do correct me if the sync process I wrote above is not right and let me know how can I work this out. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say from this little information, how complex is your data model.
If the state of your app corresponds to a single document in mongo you can just replace the previous document each time you save.

Comment: It's a single document in MongoDB database. I'm deleting all the old fields and inserting new data on every sync. It's a simple todo app. I was thinking maybe it's the right way or there is a better option.

Comment: Simple is best. Doing it this way may not scale to larger apps that require multiple documents though, so keep that in mind in the future. 
The alternative is posting the apps state to an endpoint that does all the update/upsert logic.

Comment: It's working fine, for now, it's a demo thing but I have to implement similar concept in a larger app. Deleting everything and reinserting doesn't feel like the right thing to do. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: The usual way is each action that changes the state of your app would query an api that would update it in the db. However, if a feature of your app is that it's state is only saved upon some action, then as per my last comment, you need to post its entire state to an endpoint that puts things where they need to go. I can't really help more without knowing what your data looks like. I recommend planning out your database schema first.

Comment: Okay @SpeedOfRound, thanks for the help.